# How to: create a complexType with attributes, a base type, and child element?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation, complextype

I would like to be able to validate xml element "trace" in 3 different cases, which are presented below.
I can get the restrictions and attributes to validate, and I can get the attributes and sub element to validate, but I can't get all three to validate. I.e., Case 2 is the problem; complextypes with simpleContent can't seem to contain sequences or choices. Help greatly appreciated.

Case 1

```
<trace level="info" ref="my_string"/>
```

Case 2

```
<trace level="info">
     <string id="my_str">hipster</string>
</trace>
```

Case 3

```
<trace level="info">ipsum</trace>
```

My schema

```
<xs:complexType name="string" >
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string" >
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="trace">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="string">
            <xs:attribute name="level" type="val" />
            <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:anyURI" use="optional"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

*Notice the difference between string and xs:string.

### EDIT: Solution

I found that the solution to validating each case is to add attribute "mixed" to "complexType" and set it = true. Example in schema below.

```
<xs:complexType name="string" >
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string" >
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="trace" mixed="true">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="string" type="string" />
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="level" type="val" />
    <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:anyURI" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: I actually found this question already on SO, but the solution isn't ideal.

Fortunately I found a solution, and it's quite simple: "complexType" has an attribute, "mixed" which can and should be set to true for cases like this. More info in the Edit.

Comment: You've got three very different structures here.  Why are you giving them all the same name?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the XML, it is a given.